# How to add certain % tax to the order sub total based on some condition?

Tags: magento

The Magento store that i am working has custom order wizard where one can select products with wizard like steps and finally items are added to the cart. 
And client wants to add certain % tax or surcharge to the sub-total of the cart items placed using this wizard.

Can anyone recommend the proper way of adding extra charge to the sub-total?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I thought of that but what will be the condition to apply?

Comment: Do you want it to be applied to all orders no matter what was ordered?

Comment: The store has product builder wizard and can select products of his/her choice. And finally he can add to cart those products and i want to add the tax/surcharge to the sub-total (iff items are added via custom wizard). Does that makes sense?

Comment: in that case shopping cart price rules will not work. you will need  to add your custom order totals. take a look at this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7517534/adding-a-custom-discount-order-total-in-magento-does-not-change-sales-tax

Comment: I think found one good article with downloadable module: http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-add-fee-discount-order-total

Comment: Please add it as your own answer to your question and accept it. This may help someone else.